# Cannot hide tab-number appearing below navigation panel of my shiny app

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, tabs, navbar

For the shiny app, I changed the Titlepanel settings to create a favicon and window title. However, now I get a number appearing right below the navigation panel.

Here is the code for the UI:

```
ui <- navbarPage(titlePanel(windowTitle = "Name",
                            title = tags$head(tags$link(rel = "shortcut icon",
                                                        href = "images/image.png",
                                                        type="images/image-icon"))),
                 title = "Name",
                 selected = "home",
                 theme = shinytheme("readable"),
                 fluid = TRUE)
```

Here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feaOr.png)

While I do see my favicon and window title, I cannot hide this tab number. What is the way to do this?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example can help us to help you. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is guide of how to create it.

Comment: Same issue here